# How to change 1, 2, 3, 4 to 0, 1 across multiple columns?

Tags: r, case, dplyr, tibble

There is a tibble that contains number 1 to 4.

```
library(tidyverse)

# reproducible data
sample_tbl <- structure(list(X1 = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L), 
X2 = c(1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L), X3 = c(4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L), X4 = c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X5 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 1L), X6 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L
), X7 = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), X8 = c(2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), X9 = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L), X10 = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

# A tibble: 10 x 10
      X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     4     1     4     1     1     2     3     2     2     3
 2     4     4     3     4     3     3     4     4     1     4
 3     1     4     3     3     3     4     1     4     4     1
 4     4     4     3     2     1     4     2     2     4     3
 5     1     4     2     3     2     3     3     3     2     1
 6     4     2     2     4     2     2     3     2     4     2
 7     2     4     1     2     3     4     2     3     4     1
 8     3     4     1     1     3     1     2     4     1     2
 9     2     3     4     1     4     1     2     3     3     2
10     4     2     2     1     1     3     1     4     3     3
```

I want to change 1 and 2 to 0, and 3 to 4 to 1.

Expected Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 10
      X1    X2    X3
   <int> <int>   ...
 1     1     0   ... 
 2     1     1   ... 
 3     0     1   ...
 4     1     1   ...
 5     0     1   ...
 6     1     0   ...
 7     0     1   ...
 8     1     1   ...
 9     0     1   ...
10     1     0   ...
```

I thought I could use `dplyr::mutate()`, `dplyr::across()`, `dplyr::case_when()` but I cannot figure out how.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using integer division by 3:

```
sample_tbl %/% 3

#    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
# 1   1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
# 2   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   1
# 3   0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   0
# 4   1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1   1
# 5   0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0   0
# 6   1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1   0
# 7   0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  1   0
# 8   1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   0
# 9   0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
# 10  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can loop `across` the column, create a logical vector with `%in%` on the vector of values 3, 4 and coerce it to binary

```
library(dplyr)
sample_tbl <- sample_tbl %>% 
       mutate(across(everything(),  ~ +(. %in% c(3, 4))))
```

-output

```
sample_tbl
# A tibble: 10 x 10
      X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
 2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1
 3     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
 4     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     1
 5     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     0
 6     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0
 7     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0
 8     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
 9     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     0
10     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1     1
```

---

If we need to use `case_when`

```
sample_tbl <- sample_tbl %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(. %in% c(3, 4) ~ 1, 
             . %in% c(1, 2) ~ 0)))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
sample_tbl[] <- lapply(sample_tbl, \(x)  +(x %in% c(3, 4)))
```

#### data

```
sample_tbl <- structure(list(X1 = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L), 
    X2 = c(1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L), X3 = c(4L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L), X4 = c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X5 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L), X6 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L
    ), X7 = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), X8 = c(2L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), X9 = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L), X10 = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What is the problem with using your data?

Comment: @zx8754 well, you can add the data in your post rather than refferring to my post.

Comment: Why duplicate the effort?

Comment: @zx8754 anyway, i don't like my name getting referenced.  Also, what if I delete the data?

Comment: Then my answer will suffer, and that it is OK, as the OP didn't provide reproducible data, solution is the same.

Comment: I edited OP's post and added reproducible data, no I didn't copy it from your answer.

Comment: Well, why does it matter to me.  My only point here is that you don't have to refer to the data on other person's post as it could change

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option.

Change 1 and 2 to 0 and remaining values to 1.

```
sample_tbl[sample_tbl == 1 | sample_tbl == 2] <- 0
sample_tbl[sample_tbl != 0] <- 1
sample_tbl

#      X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1
# 2     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     1
# 3     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0
# 4     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     1
# 5     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     0
# 6     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1
# 7     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     1
# 8     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     1
# 9     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
#10     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0
```